# Google Chrome - remove old tabs

Tags: chrome-for-android, tablet

When I click on a link, Chrome opens and the link will be displayed in a new tab.

However all my previous tabs are still there. By clicking multiple links again and again a new tab is opened. Over the time Chrome is stacking dozens and dozens of tabs.

How can I stop this? I don't want to manually close each and every tab.

Even closing Chrome (swipe away Chrome in recents overview) does not delete the old tabs.

I have tried reinstalling Chrome and it still shows this behavior.

Comment: Indeed Chrome on tablet is really missing a "Close all tabs" button.